# XSLT getting the first row from a series of data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have seen some very similar questions, but the solutions don't seem to work in my case.

I have XML that looks like this.

```
<AdLocInfo>
            <ExternalRunSchedNumber/>
            <RunSchedule-id>280896</RunSchedule-id>
            <publication-id>181</publication-id>
            <publication>SWEB</publication>
            <publication-placement-id>10</publication-placement-id>
            <publication-placement>Legals</publication-placement>
            <publication-position-id>21</publication-position-id>
            <publication-position>Legal - Notices</publication-position>
            <import-price>0.00</import-price>
            <rundates>
                <date Insertion-id="1530082" InvoicedAlreadyFlag="true" PublishedFlag="true" Deadline="05042017 15:30:00">05062017</date>
                <date Insertion-id="1530083" InvoicedAlreadyFlag="true" PublishedFlag="true" Deadline="05052017 15:30:00">05072017</date>
                <date Insertion-id="1530084" InvoicedAlreadyFlag="true" PublishedFlag="true" Deadline="05052017 15:30:00">05082017</date>
                <date Insertion-id="1530085" InvoicedAlreadyFlag="true" PublishedFlag="true" Deadline="05082017 15:30:00">05092017</date>
                <date Insertion-id="1530086" InvoicedAlreadyFlag="true" PublishedFlag="true" Deadline="05092017 15:30:00">05102017</date>
                <date Insertion-id="1530087" InvoicedAlreadyFlag="true" PublishedFlag="true" Deadline="05102017 15:30:00">05112017</date>
                <date Insertion-id="1530088" InvoicedAlreadyFlag="true" PublishedFlag="true" Deadline="05112017 15:30:00">05122017</date>
                <date Insertion-id="1530089" InvoicedAlreadyFlag="true" PublishedFlag="true" Deadline="05112017 15:30:00">05132017</date>
                <date Insertion-id="1530090" InvoicedAlreadyFlag="true" PublishedFlag="true" Deadline="05122017 15:30:00">05142017</date>
                <date Insertion-id="1530091" InvoicedAlreadyFlag="true" PublishedFlag="true" Deadline="05122017 15:30:00">05152017</date>
```

I want to pull the first and last dates from the series.

My XSL looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="AdBaseInfo">
        <ad>
            <paperId>5344</paperId>
            <paperItemId>
                <xsl:value-of select="Ad/AdNumber"/>
            </paperItemId>
            <itemDesc>
                <!--<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>-->
                <xsl:value-of select="Ad/ad-content"/>
                <!--<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>-->
            </itemDesc>
            <startDate>
                <xsl:for-each select="//date[1]">
                   <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 5, 4), '-', substring(., 1, 2), '-', substring(., 3, 2))" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </startDate>
```

But that results in the first line from each of the records in the XML file.

```
<ad>
<paperId>5344</paperId>
<paperItemId>0000119016-01</paperItemId>
<itemDesc/>
<startDate>2017-05-062017-05-242017-06-012017-06-012017-06-082017-05-272017-06-082017-06-082017-06-072017-06-072017-06-082017-06-082017-07-012017-06-082017-06-082017-06-072017-06-082017-06-10</startDate>
<expDate/>
<categoryId>S-Main Legal ROP</categoryId>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must start with creation of a sorted list of `date` elements (`dates`),
but not with just "ordinary" copying.

The content of this variable is created in a `for-each` loop with
`sort` instruction inside, processing **original** `date` elements.

The sort order is *year-month-day*.

Each turn of the loop adds to `dates` variable a **new** `date` node,
with just the date (a text node), but in the proper (target) format.

If for any reason you needed something more, copy to the newly created element
e.g. any attributes you need.

With the above in mind, I choose to create a list of **nodes**, not just a list of **strings**.

Then if you want to get the min or max date, it is enough to write:

- `<xsl:value-of select="$dates/date[1]"/>` or
- `<xsl:value-of select="$dates/date[last()]"/>`

Below there is a complete script, working for your sample input.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="rundates">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="dates">
        <xsl:for-each select="date">
          <xsl:sort select="concat(substring(., 5, 4),
          '-', substring(., 1, 2), '-', substring(., 3, 2))"/>
          <date>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 5, 4),
              '-', substring(., 1, 2), '-', substring(., 3, 2))" />
          </date>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <minDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="$dates/date[1]"/>
      </minDate>
      <maxDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="$dates/date[last()]"/>
      </maxDate>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AdLocInfo">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="rundates"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```